# Getting the id of an item selected by the user?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, post

In the phtml file shows all my database in a table including `price`, `id` etc , and then in the php file `Details` when the user try to press rent it takes the Id of the item and store it in the shop using the method `add` I keep getting this error

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string.
```

The reason why I store the id of the item from the database so when the user check out I ll retrieve all the information using the id of the item been selected by the user. and also I am using array list to store more then one item, another thing to mention they way of getting the id of the item is by the local variable  `$tem = $_POST(['$dvdDetails->getDvdId()']);` in the adding cart file but i am not really sure if its store the right value as there is a foreach loop and The duration of the variable will be distorted by the end of the method so how can i get the the id of the item been selected.

```
<?php
    require_once('Models/Product.php');

    class Shop {
         private $_products = array();

        public function getProducts() 
            { return $this->_products;}

        public function addProduct(Product $product) 
            { $this->_products[] = $product; 
              return $this;
            }

    }

    ?>


    <?php


    class Option {
      private $_optionKey;
        private $_optionValue;

        public function getKey()
            { return $this->_optionKey; }

        public function getVlue()
            { 
            return $this->_optionValue; 

            }

        public function setOption($key, $value)
            { 
              $this->_optionKey = $key;
              $this->_optionValue = $value;
              return $this;
            }
    }

    ?>


    <?php
    require_once('Models/Option.php');



    class Product {
        private $_options = array();

        public function getOptions()
            { return $this->_options; }

        public function addOption(Option $option)
            { $this->_options[] = $option;
              return $this;
            }
    }

    ?>
    //SHow all 
    <?php require('template/header.phtml') ?> 
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 

     <table class="datatable"> 
     <tbody> 

     <?php foreach ($view->dd as $dvdDetails) { 

     echo '<tr> <td>' 
           .'<img src="images/'. $dvdDetails->getPhotoDetails() .'"alt="no picture" height="240" width="820" />' .'<br><br>'.'<font size="3" color="#2E2E2E"><center>'. $dvdDetails->getDvdPhoto(). '</center></font>'.
             '<br><br><br>'.  '<font size="2" color="blue"><strong>Genre: </strong></font>'.  $dvdDetails->getDvdGenre() .
              '<br><br>'. '<font size="2" color="blue"><strong>Director: </strong></font>'.  $dvdDetails->getDvdDirector() . '<br><br>' .'<font size="2" color="blue"><strong>Ritels: </strong></font>'. $dvdDetails->getDvdRitels() .
             '<br><br>' . '<font size="2" color="blue"><strong>Price for rent: </strong></font>'. $dvdDetails->getDvdId()) . 
       '<br><br>' .
          '<div class="ghassar">' .
             '<div id="op"> <label>Number of days </label> <select name="days" > <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option> <option>4</option> <option>5</option> 
     </select> 
     <br><br><br><br> 

     </div> 



     <div> 



     <input type="submit" value="Add to the basket" name="rent" id="buttom1" /> 
     </div> ' . '<br><br>' .
           '<br><br>' .'<div>'.

    '</td> </td> </tr>'; 
     } ?> 
     </tbody> 
    </table>
     <?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>
```

// adding to the cart

```
<?php
require_once('Models/Dvd_sql.php'); 
require_once('Models/Shop.php');  


$view = new stdClass(); 
$view->dd = 'SQL'; 
$dvd_sql = new Dvd_sql(); 
$view->dd  = $dvd_sql->fetchAllStudents();    //->fetchAllStudents(); 
if (isset($_POST['rent']))
{
    $tem = $_POST(['$dvdDetails->getDvdId()']);
 $shop = new Shop(); $shop->addProduct($tem);
}

   require_once('Views/dvdDetails.phtml');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is get the ID of the DVD from the form page into the form processing page. Assuming that's it, there are a couple of problems with the way you're going about that.

- First, `$_POST['$dvdDetails->getDvdId()']` is looking in the post data for a string key literally matching the string '$dvdDetails->getDvdId()'. Strings in single quotes aren't interpolated by PHP, and even with double-quotes you really want to stick with simple variables and/or use `{$brackets}`.
- Second, it seems to me that the object `$dvdDetails` does not even exist in the form processing script. I only see it in the form display code, and that does not automatically transfer it over to the processing script. You'll need to explicitly pass the data you need in the form. For that, you can do something like this:

**In the form (following your string concatenation style)**

```
'<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="' . $dvdDetails->getDvdId() . '">' .
```

**in the processing script**

```
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
```

***Edit***
The first time around, I missed the fact that you're looping over many DVD items. In that case, my advice would lead to many `item_id` inputs and only one (the last, I think) will be seen by the processing script. Your "days" selector will suffer from the same problem. In this case, I think simplest solution would be to create a separate form for each DVD and use my advice above. That way only one copy of "days" and "item_id" get sent when you submit the form for a particular DVD.